# The word to know when you don’t know how to feel?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the word to use when you don’t know how to feel?

Such as instead of saying:

> He didn't know how to feel

You could say

> He felt ____.

Comment: It looks like a recursive expression.

Answer (score 6):

The perfect word for this comes from today’s slang. In the current vernacular, you would say that he felt ***meh***.  It’s recent slang that [per Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Meh) means

> Indifference; to be used when one simply does not care.

For example, from [an article on “Five Ways Not to Feel Meh” on Karousing.com](http://karousing.com/5-ways-not-feel-meh/):

> It’s easy to feel meh. Not up. Not down. Just indifferent. Apethetic. No matter how great life is, we can all fall into the lull of feeling, well, nothing. We get caught up in work, patterns, habits, and fears. I’m here to tell you that there’s a danger to feeling meh. Just like that frog in the pot of water that sits there as the temperature is turned up slowly until it’s boiled to death. Nothing kills your spirit more than the gradual and continuous malaise of feeling meh.

Although some folks might use *meh* to mean *blasé*, others use it in a much more neutral fashion.

Comment: You are saying that not knowing how to feel is the same as not caring how to feel?  When some one is shocked or hasn't had time to think, they may not know how they feel (yet).  That is not the same as ambivalence.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some words and phrases sometimes used in such a situation:
• He felt *at a loss*
• He was *[dumfounded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumfounded)* (“Shocked and speechless”)
• He was *all at sea*
• He was *[bewildered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bewildered)* (“Baffled, confused, mystified, at a loss, or uncertain”)

Comment: Note, a suggested edit (rejected, I think reasonably, by two reviewers) would have added  “He was emotionless” and “He was apathetic or in a state of apathy” to the above.  I see  *emotionless* as suggestive of coldness or callousness, rather than of uncertainty about how to feel; and *apathetic* as suggestive of not caring enough to feel.

Answer (score 3):

A common word for this condition is *[nonplussed](http://thesaurus.com/browse/nonplussed?s=t)*. The link takes you to an online thesaurus for a list of synonyms.

Comment: That is absolutely right. And it means that 'one is not sure how to react or what to do when in a situation'.

Eg. Mary was nonplussed when the hitchhiker jumped in front of her car.

Answer (score 3):

I immediately thought of the word *ambivalent*.

[***Ambivalence*** is defined as:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent?show=0&t=1369413902)

> 1. simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action
> 2. a. continual fluctuation (as between one thing and its opposite)
>      b. uncertainty as to which approach to follow

Answer (score 0):

For a common word you could use ***uncertain*** or ***unsure***, but depending on if you want to alter the phrase at all, the word ***vacillate*** or ***vacillation*** would fit perfectly in terms of meaning: "the inability to decide between different opinions or actions" - [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vacillation).

A selection of other words that mean similar are: ambivalent, irresolute, indeterminate, equivocal.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that he felt *conflicted*. That would be when he feels two (or more) apparently contradictory emotions at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

This is almost a trick question. It implies that people don't just feel emotions, they choose an emotion and slip into it. As though, for example, if I won the lottery and thought.. "ooh what's that emotion I'm supposed to have now ?..erh" and because I can't remember what it is, I never feel happy, I just feel confused. Is that the state you are talking about? You see what I mean?

If you mean he was unable to feel, then perhaps you could say *numb*.

If you mean that there is an expectation on him to feel a certain way (e.g. when someone dies) and he is not sure how to behave, then I'm not sure that one word will do it.